# Problem with configuring mod_wsgi WSGIDaemonProcess option

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualhost, pinax

I am trying to deploy Pinax bundle of Django framework + and selected applications.

Here is my apache config:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess ptest python-path=/home/pinax-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup ptest
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ptest/deploy/pinax.wsgi
```

When I restart apache I get the following error:

```
Invalid option to WSGI daemon process definition
```

Any ideas what is wrong? I am pretty sure my virtual environment at /home/pinax-env/ works.

Is any setup required for daemon process outside of apache config?

Answer (score 1):

Likely because you are using an ancient obsolete version of mod_wsgi. So, install something newer than mod_wsgi 1.X and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only configuration file outside apache config is your WSGIScriptAlias file: `pinax.wsgi`

For django you should make you own file as described here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/.

But your error is solely connected with your `WSGI` config. Try to comment out all other directives except `WSGIScriptAlias` and see if it helps.